# How to use Remote Terminal Access Plugin in Jenkins to open in-job terminal?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Im trying to have a terminal access inside Jenkins job, according to the docs i should have "Interactive Terminal" button, but after installing the plugin and upgrade Jenkins master to last version - i still cant find it... any idea ?

Thanks .

> The terminal is accessible in two ways. The first is through a
>   browser. To get there, go to the page that shows an on-going build,
>   then click "Interactive Terminal". You'll have to press the "Launch a
>   terminal" button to start a session. Multiple people can watch and
>   type into the terminal at the same time, like screen lets you.

docs: 
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+Terminal+Access+Plugin

Comment: Tried also to compile the plugin by myself as suggested at https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24212 , (i skip test due to failing unit tests) and i can see that the plugin upgraded but still cant see the terminal button that should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it work only with 'Freestyle project'.

I guess since this plugin is for adoption - its not developed and probably doesn't support Pipeline jobs.